# How do you edit quality pitched voice? (Q w/ example sample)

Tags: voice, software

Sorry, if I am a bit unclear, but I've got a quick sample (of how should it sound a bit like) [if you click here](http://www.youtube.com/embed/Y1GaeRLNXYU?start=35&end=60&version=3&rel=0&autohide=1&showinfo=0). These types of songs/editing are quite rare and can't be easily found and since they can't be found, I have no idea how to edit voices changing pitch, but not making the voice sound odd. (the edited also sounds a bit, like it is in some chords or harmony)

More examples: (as I hear them):
[1.](http://www.youtube.com/embed/JJ4ayQdv-iI?start=0&end=15&version=3&rel=0&autohide=1&showinfo=0))

Comment: Appreciate it @RoryAlsop

Comment: I wouldn't say voice pitching is rare at all, It's actually a really common practice, especially with specific hip hop artists, and EDM in general. You just need a program that can pitch up and down, and then pitch the FORMANT up and down with it. It mostly takes practice and fiddling around.

Comment: You can also just speed up or slow down the sample, but then timing can be a bear to deal with

Comment: So Audacity Pitch would do the thing? I have experimented with it, but I don't see it as the thing I am searching for

Comment: I think it'd be a great place to start practicing for sure. I haven't used it, but most pitching software works very similarly. It all comes down to LISTENING and making small adjustments. Like I said before, the formant is important, and weird sounding voice pitch often means the formant wasn't moved (in my experience).

Comment: I don't do a whole lot of pitching, so hopefully someone can write up an answer with more specifics for ya!

Comment: You could also look into vocoders, but I don't think that's what that first link used.

Comment: @Thomas I will look in to it, the general idea is to get the higher pitch voice, what is at least a bit clear. Note that the links are to just clarify a bit, I am not intending to a-a copy